# Best practice to store scorm content

Tags: scorm

I am working on an elearning application that will play SCORM contents. I am using Angular and Spring Boot for the backend. I want to know the best practice in storing the uploaded SCORM packages. I am pretty new to SCORM.

My question is : Is it advisable to save them to the server or to the assets folder in the projects folder in case of SCORM? I know that saving uploaded contents to the server is advised generally, but then how to load the associated JS and images files? I am looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Generally the SCORM contents are static files that have to be served directly from a web server and are loaded by the SCO(s) in the course. The individual SCO(s) have a file that is the entry point that are launched and the rest of the assets are loaded as typical web assets would be.

I don't know enough about your target platform to know the distinction between what you are calling "the server" and "the assets folder". Note there is a significant amount more to playing SCORM content than simply unpacking the contents and hosting them, you'll need to provide the JS runtime API, etc.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am aware of the fact that I need to expose a JS API to track the SCORM contents and I am almost done with the runtime API implementing the basic calls and the data models also. I was just unclear about how to serve the SCORM contents to the application.

Comment: you'll want to watch out for cross domain since the LMS is exposing the Runtime API, and if you try to serve it up from another mediaserver/content server it could put you into a sandbox.  For those reasons, I typically would advocate you take a index.html file and point it back to the assets on your content server so at least one file is on the same domain as the LMS

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you want to be careful with any content that a user may upload in your web app. In cases like this, I tend to take a "handler" approach.

First step is to pick somewhere that I want to keep the extracted assets. It *could* be on the server, but there are times where you can't do that (maybe you have multiple servers behind a load balancer so who knows which server the request could go to, or maybe it's just a cloud instance with ephemeral storage, or whatever) so in that case maybe you need to store the files in some external cloud disk or blob/S3 or whatever. Choose wherever makes sense for your application.

Second step is to define a handler route for package content. It doesn't have to have anything to do with how the content is currently stored. Maybe you want a route like `/lms/:pkgid/*` where `:pkgid` represents the ID of the SCORM package, and the `*` refers to the remainder of the path. Since you know where the files live, you can grab a stream to that file and pass it along as the response, making sure you have the correct mime type set.

This has a couple of advantages--one is that a person on the outside has no idea what your server file structure is, which makes it a bit more difficult to craft malicious file paths. Also, you can store the files in a location that is non-executable to the app since all you are going to do is pass along the file stream to the response. Since you have the package ID in every request, you can also make sure every request is authorized to get that file. Finally, it allows you to make changes to your file structure in the future without impacting your users. If you did start out putting them in a safe spot on your server, but then later needed to move them to a cloud location, you can just update your handler so that it knows that the file stream is in a new location, but the route (and your users' bookmarks!) don't have to change.